# Ignore vertical scrolling inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, uiwebview

One of the cells in a UITableView contains a scroll view. I want to be able to scroll the content in the cell horizontally, but NOT vertically.

How can I achieve this?

Additionally, the scroll view is a subview of UIWebView, so I cannot control its content size.

I have tried setting the content offset directly, but this prevents the entire table from being scrolled. I want the table to scroll vertically, but not the content in the cell.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: scrollView.contentOffset.x, y: 0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to ensure the content is smaller than the vertical bounds of the UIScrollView to prevent vertical scrolling, and in addition you'll need to set `scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = false`.

Comment: I cannot use this method due to the constraints of working with a UIWebView

Comment: `UIWebView` doesn't allow you to set the constraints of its frame?

Comment: I dont want the webview to have the same height as its content view. this is because the content view size gets wonky when zooming in.